# Does using collapsible elements can reduce server overload?

Tags: jquery-mobile-collapsible

For an exemple, I'm making an Iphone webapp and I intend to use jquery collapsible elements to make the app faster. So, when you do that will the collapsed elements still load and are just hidden or will it indeed help retrieve only the requested content? Thanks! ps. Any suggestions to reduce the server work by using elements that only load when requested for mobile apps would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking the element with a css hidden directive does not cause the server to skip sending that element to the browser. All the DOM elements are retrieved from the server for collapsible elements as written in you HTML file.  In order to make the server load dynamically(as you select a expandable element) you would need to add an AJAX call that loads the relevant information into the DOM when the element is expanded.